# inserting data into mysql

Tags: mysql, insert

My insert and update pages (through my admin forlder) into mysql stopped working. When I try to insert/update details it stays on the same page without adding or updating anything into the database table.

I really don't know what happened and don't know where start looking. I didn't make any change to the pages whatsoever.

Is there anyone who had the same problem and can kindly give me a clue?

Appreciated
Francesco

Insertng some code if it can be of nay help:

```
    <?php
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? addslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
mysql_select_db($database_satsconn, $satsconn);
$query_rstUname = "SELECT members_ID FROM members WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'";
$rstUname = mysql_query($query_rstUname, $satsconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rstUname = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstUname);
$totalRows_rstUname = mysql_num_rows($rstUname);
if($totalRows_rstUname > 0){
$error['uname'] = 'That username is already in use. Please choose another.';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['pwd']) && isset($_POST['pwd'])) {
 if($_POST['pwd'] != $_POST['con_pwd']) {
   $error['pwd'] = 'Your passwords don\'t match.';
   }
  else {
  $_POST['pwd'] =md5($_POST['pwd']);
  }
}

if(!isset($error)) {
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "addUser")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO members (realname, username, pwd) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['realname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['pwd'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_satsconn, $satsconn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $satsconn) or die(mysql_error());
   }
}

if ((isset($_POST['members_ID'])) && ($_POST['members_ID'] != "")) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM members WHERE members_ID=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['members_ID'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_satsconn, $satsconn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $satsconn) or die(mysql_error());

  $deleteGoTo = "add_member.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_satsconn, $satsconn);
$query_rstAdmin = "SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY realname ASC";
$rstAdmin = mysql_query($query_rstAdmin, $satsconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rstAdmin = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstAdmin);
$totalRows_rstAdmin = mysql_num_rows($rstAdmin);
?>
```

Comment: Some code would be helpfull, or any error/log messages?

Comment: You say 'through my admin folder' => in what admin tool?

Comment: I have an admin forder with all files to insert/update/delele fiels into database. 

All files worked fine they inseted and updated details into tables, but suddently they don't work.

There are no error messages at all.

Comment: does your page show a signs of reloading? you you just press a button with no effect? do you have any javascript in your edit form?

Comment: Yes I do have some java script.

Comment: No sing of reloading and when pressed button no effect.
Previously all worked fine (for a long while).

Comment: Well looks like some javascript prevent this form from submit

Comment: for what I recall no tall pages where this is happening have java script in it, but it is a good start to look at. Thank you.

Comment: I have just noticed one more thing: on my localhost pages work fine but they don't wrok on my remote server, where they worked before anyway.

Comment: Even if you repeat these words "they worked before anyway" thousand times, it won't help you a bit :)

Comment: Don't you have anything else to do? I know what to do now look into the code and find the problem. I am sure I will find it.

I suggest you go for a walk.

Comment: there are techniques, thousand times more effective than just looking into code - that's what I'm trying to explain. but as you wish

Comment: maybe, but you are making your help very hard inedeed

Comment: Please give more details on "local host pages" and "remote server".

Comment: On Locahost I am working with apache server, mysql and php5. All works fine. Remote server is a linux, mysql, with php5 activated.

All pages when inserting or updating details into database work fine but on the remote server they stopped working. Nothing happens, when clicking "submit" pages stay there.

Comment: most probably it has nothing to do with mysql.

Comment: First of all need to decide if it's a javascript (client-side) or server-side problem. To answer this question you need to check if your web browser shows page as loading or it's just doesn't do anything (= submit button doesn't work).

Comment: I am pretty sure is a server-side problem. I have tried without any java script and still does not work.

Can it be some sort of server configuration that is making the problem? Bisides all works perfectly on my local server.
Thank you for coming back to this (still unsolved) problem Andriy
Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"it stays on the same page without adding or updating anything" is very common problem and can be caused by thousands of errors. There is noway to solve it by finding "anyone who had the same problem".

If you're just user of this code, it would be better to hire a programmer.

If you supposed to be a programmer yourself, you have to learn how to `debug` your application. Debugging stands for finding where the error is. Although debugging could help only if you know, what your code does. You can try it anyway.

There are many things to do. You have to be sure that you can see all possible errors. 
You can start from [this useful article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-debug/)

Comment: When is said "anyone  who had the same problem..." I meant when all worked fine and well and suddently for no reason it stopped working. Without making any changes to the pages and without giving any error.

I am pretty sure the code is fine.
Your comment is noted (sic!) but pretty useless.

Comment: @francesco no, it is not useless. You just don't understand programming basics :) There is no magic wand to tell you where is the problem and how to solve it. It's **hard work**. And you're going into it. But the information from the link in my post could ease it. Anyway, it is your duty to determine at least where the problem is - in the browser. or in the php or in the mysq. Noone can do it for you.

Comment: The problem (and also my question) is why all worked fine for a long while and now it stopped?

Is not question of understanding programm basics, which I do, it is just how can some code work fine for a long while but suddently it doesn't? Code is not changed.

What I am asking is a clue about how something like that can even happen. I can go deep into the code and try to find the problem but I would like to do it wiht come clues in mind.

Comment: @francesco your code runs not in the vacuum. It runs on the server, in the browser, on the PC. It is called environment and it can cause problems even while your code didn't change. Does this answer suit you?

Comment: I am not sure. If it is meant to be offensive, No. Still you are offending  me assuming that I am an absolutely prick and don't know what I am doing. I think we better stop here. 
Your help was appreciated.

Comment: @francesco no, I am not offending but you don't know what you're doing. That's a fact. Facts cannot be offensive. And in this latter comment I merely answered your question and nothing more. Being too touchy won't help you to set your app to working. C'mon pal, lets go to the programming topics. Do you confirm it's client side problem?

Comment: The problem in only on my linux server. On my localhost all works fine.
php 5 on both

Comment: @francesco no, no. every web application has 2 parts: server side and client side. even if your website runs on the linux server, you see your update form in your browser, on your PC. It is called "client side". If your form refuse to submit - it's client side problem. Does your admin folder use any AJAX features?

Comment: PS: are you a teacher? Your "no" sounds like a teacher speaking.

Comment: So we know that there is a problem with my code. How come the same code workd ok on my local server and not on the remote server?

There is some ajax but not on those pages

Answer (score 0):

I see there's a lot of `if(isset($variable))` on the code. What happens if `isset($_POST['MM_insert'])` returns false? Put some error traps (a simple echo telling that the variable isn't set will do) to see where exactly the code stops working, and then you'll see why it stopped working.
Also, try using `print_r()` on the possible-problematic variable to see if you're getting exactly what you're expecting.
PS: I'd use only one db selection. I think there's no need to do it more than once in this case, except you explicitly need and want to use a different db.